# Bag of Words Representation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I would like to implement bag of words representation for my project. I computed the codebook of visual words of images by using their features and descriptors.Then, I obtained cluster centers using k-means. For the bag of words representation part, it is asked that you should use manually labeled segments provided as part of the dataset. In dataset, there are three different binary masks for each image. Are those labeled segments that binary masks? If so, how will I use that computed visual words?

Comment: Without seeing the data, it's hard to say. But I think that yes, the labeled segments are the pixels selected by the binary masks. I think the assignment wants you to use the features of the masked segments to train your visual words rather than a sliding window or other way of choosing segments from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bag of words approach provides a concise representation of an image or a part of an image. That representation is typically used as an input to a classification algorithm which is used to estimate the class to which the image data belongs. Typically, the classifier is a supervised learning method which will require pairs (descriptor, label) from some training set during the training process. In your case, the descriptor is the BOW representation of the image data from your training set. Then, during testing you will feed the BOW descriptor of new image data to the classifier to infer the class.

From what I understand, the fact that you have three different masks for the images, means that you also have three classes. Then, each mask will tell you which part of an image should be considered image data belonging to a particular class. This is your training data.

Under that assumption, you should extract the parts of the images that correspond to each mask, compute the BOW representation for those image parts (separately for each mask) and use those with the mask number as a label to train the classifier.

This will allow you to later to e.g. use the sliding window approach to classify parts of a test image as belonging to one of the 3 classes used during training. That would be a simple case of a detection problem.

I am not sure I understood your problem correctly, but I hope that this will help you move forward a bit.

Comment: I accomplished the bag of words representation for each mask by using  the function in that link: (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43631-compute-bag-of-visual-word-representation-for-an-image)  However, It is said that you should have the bag of words representation and the object label for each segment. That function computes id vector and the histogram for each mask. Are those id values that object labels? @Andrzej